# Issue when recording sound through browser

Tags: javascript, audio, audio-recording

I'm currently working on audio record through web browser (.wav format) and currently we use the following code to start record, and emit data via socket :

```
async start () {
this.stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
  audio: true,
  video: false
})
this.audioCtx = new AudioContext()
const source = this.audioCtx.createMediaStreamSource(this.stream)
const scriptProcessor = this.audioCtx.createScriptProcessor(0, 1, 1)
source.connect(scriptProcessor)
scriptProcessor.connect(this.audioCtx.destination)
scriptProcessor.onaudioprocess = event => {
  this.emit('record', event.inputBuffer.getChannelData(0))
}
return {
  device: this.stream.getAudioTracks().length && this.stream.getAudioTracks()[0].label || 'Unknown',
  sampleRate: this.audioCtx.sampleRate
}
```

Although it seems to work well, it seems that randomly, silent sequences are inserted in the data emitted (~8 consecutive frames, [sample](http://hpics.li/90d5bc9)). This doesn't seems to be hardware related as we have the same issue regardless of the microphone used.

I would like to know if it's the way we collect the data or how we send them that causes this issue. (and possibly how to fix it)

Thanks,